# How to create a nnkUInt16Lit NimNode

Tags: macros, nim-lang

There's no documentation on this except to describe the `nnkUInt16Lit` enum variant and this AST representation `42'i16  -  nnkInt16Lit(intVal = 42)`.

When I use it as we would with a regular `nnkIntLit` it fails.

```
macro test(): stmt =
  var n = newNimNode(nnkUInt16Lit)
  n.intVal = 1

  result = newLetStmt(ident("foo"), n)

test()
echo foo
```

This gives an error:

> field `intVal` cannot be found

*(This isn't my actual usage. It's just a demo to show the issue.)*

I've tried different variations on `intVal`, but the error always turns to `undeclared identifier`. I would use `parseExpr()`, but it seems that the `$` proc on an `int` doesn't work at compile time.

I've tried looking for the source code of the `NimNode` type definition to examine it but am unable to find it so far.

So how can I create a `uint16` NimNode in a macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var n = parseExpr "1'u16"
```

With this pull request your original code will work as well: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/2754

Comment: Yes, but the `int` I'm receiving isn't a constant value and as I mentioned, the `$` doesn't seem to work at compile time... unless you happen to know a trick?

Comment: That's great! Hopefully it'll be merged soon.

Comment: I built a quick `itoa` proc as a temporary solution to use with `parseExpr` until your fix is committed. Thanks much!